# GTM ecommerce datalayer not pushing to analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-datalayer

I'm trying to set up ecommerce tracking using Google Tag Manager however I cannot get the data to appear within google analytics?

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en

From using the example provided on the above link, this is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
        'transactionId': '1238393768',
        'transactionAffiliation': 'Website Name',
        'transactionTotal': 105.78,
        'transactionTax': 21.156,
        'transactionShipping': 18.00,
        'transactionProducts': [
            {
            'sku': '97',
            'name': 'Test Product 1',
            'category': 'Test Category One, Test Category Two',                
            'price': 13.99,
            'quantity': 24            
            },
            {
            'sku': '97',
            'name': 'Test Product 2',
            'category': 'Test Category One, Test Category Two',                
            'price': 3.99,
            'quantity': 22            
            },
        ]
        });
        </script>  
        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-CODE');</script>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
        <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-CODE"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone advise why this isn't working and how I can get the data to appear within Google Analytics?

One thing I don't understand is how / where it knows to add the data to my analytics account? Is there anything else I need to do or any configuration needed within GTM or GA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not push before the scripts of tag manager. It should be a initialization of the variable. Like:

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [{
    'pageCategory': 'signup',
    'visitorType': 'high-value'
  }];
</script>
```

EDIT: Documentation https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Comment: Data layer push can be made, and in fact should be made, before the GTM snippet, if that's what you mean, especially if the data is to be captured by GTM before the transaction tag has fired.

Comment: @nyuen You can only push after the declaration of dataLayer and as the documentation advise its preferable to just initialize it and after the snippet use .push

Comment: Hi @Marco, doing a push immediately after initialising the data layer is the same thing as what you are suggesting, which is also what OP is doing, which is also what his link indicates to do. So I don't believe that would be the issue.